# Launching multiple .exe in python sometimes fails

Tags: python, python-2.7, parallel-processing, jobs

I have an executable which I want to run on many different data files. I have 16 cores which I want to use, so I want to launch 16 different jobs from a python script.

I launch the jobs in a for loop like this:

```
for ii in range(NoDirectories): #NoDirectories is equal to the number of jobs I want to launch
    print("cd "+MyDir+SubDirectories[ii])
    os.chdir(MyDir+SubDirectories[ii])#directories where I want to launch the jobs

    exesymlink = "ln -s "+MyExecutablePath+"./"
    os.system(exesymlink)
    
    launchcomm = "nohup ./MyExecutable -l "+SubFileNames[ii]+" > log"+str(ii)+".txt &" #-l attaches a list of data files to run over, SubFileNames[ii] 
    print launchcomm
    os.system(launchcomm)
```

The commands are printed fine and the terminal makes it seem like they're launched:

```
cd /OutputDirectory/SubList_0
nohup ./MyExecutable -l SubList_0.txt > log0.txt &
cd /OutputDirectory/SubList_1
nohup: redirecting stderr to stdout
nohup ./MyExecutable -l SubList_1.txt > log1.txt &
cd /OutputDirectory/SubList_2
nohup: redirecting stderr to stdout
nohup ./MyExecutable -l SubList_2.txt > log2.txt &
...
```

but when I check with top only a certain number actually get launched, and this number changes from time to time. It's always the first ones that *aren't* launched though, so if 10 jobs get launched they're always jobs 7-16, while jobs 1-6 wouldn't be launched.

If I copy and paste the commands that I print to the terminal it works fine.

I've tried adding in a `time.sleep(1)` but this stops anything from being launched at all.

Why does it behave so randomly and how can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

In the end I never found a real solution but I found a relatively convenient workaround: I write the `cd` and `nohup` commands to a `.txt` file and launch them using `source mytextfile.txt`. This at least works, even if it's not a direct solution to the problem.